# Symfony comprobation buttons best practices

Tags: forms, symfony, button, controller, twig

Reading the Best Practices for Symfony at http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html it says that it's recommended that the buttons are added in the template, not in the form class nither in the controller as follows:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create"
         class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The problem is that in this way, the button is not "part" of the form, so... in my controller I can't validate if the button is Clicked:

```
if ($form->get('myButton')->isClicked)
```

Always throws me the error: Child "myButton" does not exist. This happens even if I create the button by this way:

```
<button id="form_button" name="form[button]">Button</button>
```

I know the id and name has this format in symfony... So... I don't understand why they recommends to create the buttons in the template if they will not be part of the form... Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: They recommends to create buttons in templates for reusable forms (save/edit etc.) but if you want do it other way, just do it, don't waste your time on searching why they, why I...

Comment: I know , in fact , I 'm using a generic form to create and edit a person , but I have 2 buttons: one for cancel and one for save (edit or create)... That's why I need to know which button was pressed, but the "save" button is not detected if I create it in the template